# Objective C: Class containing single NSInteger need releasing ? 

Tags: objective-c, memory

I have a class which contains single NSInteger property

```
@interface myTag
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger tag;
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@end
```

I using it in code like

```
mytag = [[myTag alloc] init];
int num = (int)mytag.tag; 
[mytag release];
NSLog(@"num = %d",num);
```

my questions are

1. In objc,all class run in pointer, that means mytag.tag return
   pointer ?
2. So num is invalid ?
3. Do i really need to call [mytag release], because nsinteger is not
   really class,just typedef of int.

But if I  not call release, the Xcode analyzer warns me about memory leak

Comment: @Aberrant not a duplicate of that one..OP is asking whether a class containing NSInteger needs releasing..

Comment: Oooooh wait, myTag is the class, the lower case m confused me. Alright, no duplicate then, removing the comment.

Comment: @lerosua Also whey you have time, make sure to read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, mytag.tag returns the value of NSInteger variable tag.
2. num is valid
3. You need to call [mytag release] because you alloc'ing it..*Simple rule of objective C memory management is whatever you alloc/retain/copy, you need to release*.

Also your third question, you are asking about mytag variable, which is not NSInteger, but an instance of myTag class..

A small advice for you, before jumping into projects , please take some time to read objective C memory management basics (which are not so easy, I must say)..Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) is a good place to start..[this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) tutorial is very informative about ARC..